# jquery and ajax file uploader won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to follow the sample code of jquery and ajax file uploader but i've got some error.
actually i cannot figure out the error because when i press the submit button, nothing happens. Please help me about this error.

The Controller:

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('files_model');
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index() 
{
$this->load->view('upload');
}

public function upload_file()
{
$status = "";
$msg = "";
$file_element_name = 'userfile';

if (empty($_POST['title']))
{
$status = "error";
$msg = "Please enter a title";
}

if ($status != "error")
{
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
$config['max_size']  = 1024 * 8;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
{
$status = 'error';
$msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
}
else
{
$data = $this->upload->data();
$file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
if($file_id)
{
$status = "success";
$msg = "File successfully uploaded";
}
else
{
unlink($data['full_path']);
$status = "error";
$msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
}
}
@unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}

public function files()
{
$files = $this->files_model->get_files();
$this->load->view('files', array('files' => $files));
}

public function delete_file($file_id)
{
if ($this->files_model->delete_file($file_id))
{
$status = 'success';
$msg = 'File successfully deleted';
}
else
{
$status = 'error';
$msg = 'Something went wrong when deleteing the file, please try again';
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
}
?>
```

The Model:

```
<?php
class Files_Model extends CI_Model {

public function insert_file($filename, $title)
{
$data = array(
'file_name'     => $filename,
'file_path'        => $title
);
$this->db->insert('files', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function get_files()
{
return $this->db->select()
->from('files')
->get()
->result();
}

public function delete_file($file_id)
{
$file = $this->get_file($file_id);
if (!$this->db->where('id', $file_id)->delete('files'))
{
return FALSE;
}
unlink('./files/' . $file->filename);  
return TRUE;
}

public function get_file($file_id)
{
return $this->db->select()
->from('files')
->where('id', $file_id)
->get()
->row();
}

}
?>
```

The View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/site.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload File</h1>
<form method="post" action="" id="upload_file">
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />

<label for="userfile">File</label>
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<h2>Files</h2>
<div id="files"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript:

```
$(function() {
$('#upload_file').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajaxFileUpload({
url         :'./upload/upload_file/', 
secureuri      :false,
fileElementId  :'userfile',
dataType    : 'json',
data        : {
'title'           : $('#title').val()
},
success  : function (data, status)
{
if(data.status != 'error')
{
$('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
refresh_files();
$('#title').val('');
}
alert(data.msg);
}
});
return false;
});
});

function refresh_files()
{
$.get('./upload/files/')
.success(function (data){
$('#files').html(data);
});
}

$('.delete_file_link').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?'))
{
var link = $(this);
$.ajax({
url         : './upload/delete_file/' + link.data('file_id'),
dataType : 'json',
success     : function (data)
{
//files = $(#files);
files = $(files);
if (data.status === "success")
{
link.parents('li').fadeOut('fast', function() {
$(this).remove();
if (files.find('li').length == 0)
{
files.html('<p>No Files Uploaded</p>');
}
});
}
else
{
alert(data.msg);
}
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: You can use Chrome/Firefox developer tools in the browser and check what is failing. Dev Tools, has all kinds of debugging help like break points and all. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Comment: Indeed, like @LearningNeverStops says, try see what the javascript console says

Comment: i am using firefox and i am a newbie of CI that is why im so very slow following the codes

Comment: i'd try on chrome. the code work. maybe its my firefox have a problem